# How do I extract function names from function calls in .erb files?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, antlr, erb

I'm just starting with ANTLR(with Java) and I need some help with parsing .erb files.
Let's say I have this Code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class ='title'> <h1>BLABLA</h1></div>

<div class = 'log'>
 <%= form_tag('/home/login', :method => 'get') do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= label_tag(:nick, 'Nickname:') %>
      <%= text_field_tag(:nick) %>
    </td>
    <td><%= label_tag(:password, 'Password:') %>
      <%= password_field_tag(:password) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <%= submit_tag('Login') %>
 <% end %>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the easiest way to extract the names for the called functions? I would need a list like this: ["form_tag","label_tag","text_field_tag","password_field_tag","submit_tag"]

I really don't need anything else, so taking the HTML grammar and adapting from the ANTRL Github seems a little overkill.

Thank you for reading/helping.

Comment: As a shortcut, you could scan for all `<%= %>` and `<% %>`  blocks and parse them as ruby.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you mean basically, take all strings between the tags, put them together and use a ruby antlr grammar?

Comment: Something like that, yes. Or apply some quick-and-dirty regexes, as in @mudasobwa's answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it’s long-and-clean!

Answer (score 1):

```
code.scan(/(?<=<%=).*?(?=%>)/)
    .map { |s| s[/(?<=\A=|\A).*?(?=\()/].to_s.strip }
    .reject(&:empty?)  # remove possible false positives
#⇒ [
#  [0] "form_tag",
#  [1] "label_tag",
#  [2] "text_field_tag",
#  [3] "label_tag",
#  [4] "password_field_tag",
#  [5] "submit_tag"
# ]
```

There are two regexes here:

- `(?<=<%=).*?(?=%>)` simply uses positive [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (both lookaheads and  lookbehinds.)
- `(?<=\A=|\A).*?(?=\()` is mostly the same, but it looks between the beginning of string (possibly followed by an equal sign) and the opening parenthesis.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Java adopts PCRE :)

Comment: Thank you @mudasobwa . Unfortunately I'm not using Ruby though(forgot to mention that). I'm using Java with ANTLR4 to tp parse ERB files/Ruby

Comment: PCRE - ok, maybe. But your 3 lines of elegant chaining will be 50-100 lines of ugly object juggling :)

Comment: Do you maybe have some sort of info ,that helps me understand this regex? :D

Comment: I'm thinking of retracting my upvote on the grounds of seeing leading dot chaining... Everyone knows that trailing dot is vastly superior!

Comment: @pokeahontas: "that helps me understand this regex?" - https://regex101.com

Comment: I have added the explanations.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev leading dots are the ground of hiding things in unix philosophy. The trailing dots, OTOH, makes the reader think that the sentence is already over.

Comment: In elixir/erlang, maybe. Nobody thinks that in ruby. :) AND trailing dot is irb/pry-friendly. Which is a huge undisputable win. IMHO, etc.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you!